# Braid groups representations on infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: rt.representation-theory, braid-groups, braided-tensor-categories

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional complex vector space. Let $R:V\otimes V\to V\otimes V$ be a solution to the quantum Yang Baxter Equation. In other words: $R$ is invertible and satisfies the equation
$$R_{23}R_{12}R_{23} = R_{12}R_{23}R_{12}.$$
This gives us, for every $n$, a representation of the Braid group $B_n$ on $V^{\otimes n}$. Let us write $$\phi_n:\mathbb{C}B_n\to End_{\mathbb{C}}(V^{\otimes n})$$ for the resulting algebra homomorphism.

It is easy to see that if $Im(\phi_n)$ is finite dimensional, then $Im(\phi_m)$ is finite dimensional for every $m\leq n$.

I would like to ask if the following is true:

There exists a natural number $n$ for which the following holds: if $Im(\phi_n)$ is finite dimensional, then $Im(\phi_N)$ is finite dimensional for every $N\geq n$.

Comment: Why do you think it might be true for every $R$? I certainly do not know the answer, but it would be nice to understand the intuition.

Comment: I hope it will be. I do not know if this is indeed the case. The reason for me asking this question is that it will enable me to construct some very general symmetric monoidal categories (this condition will ensure me that after checking finitely many hom spaces for finite dimensionality, I already know that all hom spaces are finite dimensional).